# MONTH(GetDate()) SQL Server 2008 R2 returning wrong month

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to get a start year/month and end year/month for a simple report. In my stored procedure I have the following:

```
IF @parm_StartYear is null SET @parm_StartYear = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YYYY,DATEADD(YYYY, -1, GETDATE())));
IF @parm_StartMonth is null SET @parm_StartMonth = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(MM,MONTH(GETDATE())));
IF @parm_EndYear is null SET @parm_EndYear = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE()));
IF @parm_EndMonth is null SET @parm_EndMonth = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(MM,MONTH(GETDATE())));
```

The Years are correct but the month is one month ahead. Ie. Today is December (12) but it's returning January (01).

Am I missing something simple or doing something completely wrong? Every example and other questions I look at show this exact code, more or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't cast `getdate()` to a month- so this works:

```
IF @parm_EndMonth is null SET @parm_EndMonth = CONVERT(CHAR(2),DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()));
```

Comment: OMG. So simple, thank you. I wasted hours on this haha. Cheers!

Comment: the `MONTH()` call isn't a cast: it's a function call

Comment: For some reason I thought I needed the Month() call to get the month part of the date to convert. I was confusing myself.

Comment: [Bad Habits To Kick: using shorthand with date operators](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 0):

This expression makes no sense:

```
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(MM,MONTH(GETDATE())));
```

When you call `MONTH(GETDATE())`, you already have an integer result. You don't use the `DATEPART()` function on an integer. I was amazed at first that this doesn't produce an error, until I remember that Sql Server stored dates in a numeric format internally. Then I realized that the expression will return results for the day number 12 since Sql Server's epoch, in this case: January 13, 1900. That explains your `1` result. You can see it if you try this statement in a query window:

```
SELECT cast(12 as datetime)
```

All you really need is this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(GETDATE()))
```

I'm also wondering why you're looking for character results here at all. If you want separate fields, I'd really just stop with the integer, and let client code worry about making it a string:

```
MONTH(GETDATE())
```

With a variable name that includes the `parm` token, I'm worried your passing this to another procedure that is doing some really horrible things with strings as dates, when it should just be working with `DateTime` values.